# IONIC 2, How to match versions for Google Service, PushNotifications and Firebase

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm in trouble with ionic2/cordova (Again). I don't know how to match the versions of :
 `com.google.android.gms`, `cordova-plugin-firebase` and `phonegap plugin push`.

At the en of compile i have the following error :

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.038 secs
Error: /home/thor/Projects/App_CDP/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: /home/thor/Projects/App_CDP/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/FCMService.java:71: error: cannot access zza
    String from = message.getFrom();
                         ^
 class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found
```

I understood it was because of a version difference between Google services and PushNotifications.
I have the following dependencies in gradle.build :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
     compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+"
     compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+"
     compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+"
     compile "com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.0"
     compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
     compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1"
     // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

The problem is that this file is auto-generated so i can't change it and cordova plugins are a pain.

Here is my plugin list :

```
$ ionic cordova plugins
> cordova plugin ls
✔ Running command - done!
com.googlemaps.ios 2.4.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 1.1.1 "cordova-android-play-
services-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.5 "cordova-googlemaps-plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.0.0 "PushPlugin"
```

And here are my versions :

```
$ ionic -v
3.13.1
$ cordova -v
7.1.0
```

Comment: I've save issue, Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I got solution for me here:

Step 1: Remove existing phonegap-plugin-push

```
ionic cordova plugin rm phonegap-plugin-push
```

Step 2: Add same plugin with version : 1.10.5

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push@1.10.5 --variable SENDER_ID="xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Step 3: Remove platform android and than add it.

```
ionic cordova platform rm android

ionic cordova platform add android
```

Step 4: Finally create a build for android

```
ionic cordova build android
```

If this steps not working than please refer at
/project_name/platforms/android/project.properties

```
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11+
```

Have fun :)